# Amcharts Pie Prevent Caching

Tags: caching, amcharts

It seems that Amchart is caching the json and it is not drawing the graph nor legend.

First time I open the modal it displays fine, but if I close it and open again it displays all the data in labels (taken from the same JSON), but the chart is not being drawed. Is it a caching issue?

This is the way I am drawing it:

```
var modelPie = @Html.Raw(jsonPie);
var dataProvider = [];
dataProvider = modelPie.UsefulLifes;


var chartdivdounut = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdivdounut", {
    "type": "pie",
    "startDuration": 0,
    "theme": "light",
    "addClassNames": true,
    "legend": {
        "position": "right",
        "marginRight": 0,
        "autoMargins": false
    },
    "innerRadius": "30%",
    "defs": {
        "filter": [{
            "id": "shadow",
            "width": "200%",
            "height": "200%",
            "feOffset": {
                "result": "offOut",
                "in": "SourceAlpha",
                "dx": 0,
                "dy": 0
            },
            "feGaussianBlur": {
                "result": "blurOut",
                "in": "offOut",
                "stdDeviation": 5
            },
            "feBlend": {
                "in": "SourceGraphic",
                "in2": "blurOut",
                "mode": "normal"
            }
        }]
    },
    "dataProvider": dataProvider,
    "valueField": "Value",
    "titleField": "FieldName",
    "showZeroSlices": false,
    "labelsEnabled": false,
    "export": {
        "enabled": true
    }
});

chartdivdounut.addListener("init", handleInit);

chartdivdounut.addListener("rollOverSlice", function (e) {
    handleRollOver(e);
});

function handleInit() {
    
    chartdivdounut.legend.addListener("rollOverItem", handleRollOver);
}

function handleRollOver(e) {
    var wedge = e.dataItem.wedge.node;
    wedge.parentNode.appendChild(wedge);
}
```

Comment: Need more info about how you are displaying your popup. Are you executing the above code every time you open a chart popup? Working demo would also be helpful. P.S. the chart does not do any caching, it's just if you are creating the new object in the same container without first destroying the previous chart object, conflicts might occur.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the script section in the partial view was being executed just one time.

Seems to be something messed up. I re-wrote that part of the code and it started to work properly.